# How to use JSONObject from Kotlin JS

Tags: kotlin-js

I am new to Kotlin JS.

I am trying to port the business logic of my android app to Kotlin JS.

My app uses the class org.json.JsonObject to do custom serialization. I can't use KotlinX serialization with annotations because my classes are inline and these annotations are not supported.

The Kotlin-JS project uses Gradle Kotlin DSL. I am specifying the dependency as "implementation ("org.json:json:20190722")". The compiler throws the error "unresolved reference" for anything from the library. I suspect it is not legal to link to a java library this way for Kotlin-JS. Is this true?

What is the best way to get an implementation of JsonObject into my app? Do I need to copy the source code into my project and compile it to JS myself?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the annotations in the `kotlinx.serizalization` library, you can still include it in your android and js platforms.

You will just need to construct and use the `JsonObject` type that is present on both platforms manually.

You can see the JsonObject definition in the library here:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/ffe216f0293231b09eea24a10aa4bc26ff6d5b90/runtime/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/json/JsonElement.kt#L217

Here is an example of manually constructing a JsonObject using kotlinx.serialization classes

```
data class AnalyticsEvent(
    val name: Event,
    val columns: Map<Column, JsonPrimitive>? = null,
    val properties: Map<Property, JsonElement>? = null
) : LoggingEvent() {
    override fun toJson(): JsonObject {
        val content: MutableMap<String, JsonElement> = mutableMapOf()

        content[EVENT_NAME_KEY] = JsonPrimitive(name.actual)

        val columnJSON = columns?.mapKeys { it.key.actual }
        columnJSON?.let {
            content[EVENT_COLUMNS_KEY] = JsonObject(columnJSON)
        }

        val propertiesJSON = properties?.mapKeys { it.key.actual }
        propertiesJSON?.let {
            content[EVENT_PROPERTIES_KEY] = JsonObject(propertiesJSON)
        }

        return JsonObject(content)
    }
```